# Swipe Refresh em api 15

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que muito utiliza o swipe refresh, gostaria de saber como implementar o swipe refresh em androids com api 15? Caso não seja possível como posso criar o swipe para android que o suportam e uma alternativa para os outros?

Answer (score 0):

Poderá usar o [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html) na versão 9 e seguintes se usar as [Bibliotecas de Suporte](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html).

No *xml* use:

```
android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
```

[Configuração da Biblioteca de Suporte.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

Comment: O problema é que estou utilizando a biblioteca em questão em meu XML. Porém quando atualizo o preview na api 16. Ocorre um erro.

Comment: Tem de dizer qual é o erro. Eu não sou adivinho. :)